# How to set different simulator in BlackBerry - Java Plug-in for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have downloaded & installed ***BlackBerry - Java Plug-in for Eclipse***. It is launching default simulator (*BlackBerry Bold 9930*) when I try to run an application. But I want to run the application with another simulator (e.g. *BlackBerry Torch 9800*).

How should I switch to that simulator? Is there any configuration changes or any new installation required?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the desired simulator installed (e.g. Torch 9800), then it is possible to change the run configuration and make the simulator as default simulator. Following steps will show how to change run configuration.

- On the **Run** menu, click **Run Configurations**.
- Create new configuration *(Image 1)*. On **JRE** tab, select a JRE
  *(Image 2)*.
- In **Projects** tab select a project, and apply changes.
- In **Simulator** tab select a simulator *(Image 3)*, and apply changes.

> But If you don't have the simulator installed, check following
>   article.
>
> [Specify a BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator that is installed outside
>   of the Eclipse environment](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specify_external_BB_Smrtphn_smltr_bundle_1017106_11.jsp).

***Change Run Configuration:***

***Image 1: Create New Configuration***

[image: Create New Configuration]

***Image 2: Select JRE***

[image: Select JRE]

***Image 3: Select Simulator***

[image: Select Simulator]

Comment: As i want to run application using torch simulator first i had downloaded that torch simulator but when i launched through that simulator it gets error message as illegal argument exception.As i can see in your image there are JRE 5.0,6.0,7.0 but in my eclipse i can see only JRE 7.0 so is there any JRE problem or anything else?

Comment: Yes, some simulator requires specific version of JRE (BlackBerry OS).

Comment: Thanks For Reply. Can you tell me which JRE Version requires for TORCH?

Comment: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java I tried this URL to download update for blackberry  JRE but its not working is there any another URL to update JRE?

Comment: I have installed 3 versions of BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse to avoid these sort of problems. Installed plugin versions 1.5.0 (OS 7), 1.3.0 (OS 6) and 1.1.2 (OS 5). Torch 9800 simulator was added with 1.3.0.

Comment: Not sure why the url is not working (It worked for me). You can try this link, http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/BlackBerry-Java-Plug-in-for-Eclipse.shtml.

Comment: your given link redirect to me :https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/ please tell me what should i do next ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check that link before sending.

Comment: Is there any other URL for downloading?