# Blackberry simulator in Eclipse plug in1.5

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, simulator

I have eclipse plugin version 1.5 Helios.It has a default simulator 9930 bold.

I want other simulator in my plugin.How to add other simulator like Curve-9550/Torch-9860.

Presently My eclipse has single Simulator.

Comment: Check this link, `How to set different simulator in eclipse?`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299648/how-to-set-different-simulator-in-eclipse

Comment: I tried it but I can see only one jre i.e jre 7.0.  Also I cant see other simulator than default.

Comment: I think `Specify a BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator that is installed outside of the Eclipse environment` describes what you want, and you didn't read that answer carefully.

Comment: I Read it again,But fails to get the required simulator.What to do?

Comment: finally resolved my Problem.I follow this link- http://ridz.sg/blog/2009/06/setting-up-for-blackberry-development-how-to-add-simulators-to-the-bb-jde/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download simulators from [blackberry website](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp)

Comment: Yes.I download it from blackberry website.But how to put that into eclips.

Comment: install it. it will go to the default location(like C:\Program Files\Research In Motion).then restart the eclipse. then you can see the simulators in ->Run configuration- simulators.

Comment: I installed it.But cant see it in simulator list.Only default simulator is there.

Comment: on C:\Program Files\Research In Motion , you can see it ?

Comment: No I cant see there.But Its default path is                      C:\Users\EIWA5\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 7.0.0\7.0.0.384 (9860)

Comment: when u install new simulator, then set its location as C:\Users\EIWA5\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\

Comment: I set this but in eclips I cant see it.I can see only default simulator

Comment: join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-and-java and ask here.

Comment: finally resolved my Problem.I follow this link- http://ridz.sg/blog/2009/06/setting-up-for-blackberry-development-how-to-add-simulators-to-the-bb-jde/

Answer (score 1):

For 9000 Bold simulator----

```
1.Open the file “SimPackage-JDE.rc” which should be found in your **eclipse** simulator folder. It should be in <JDEInstallDirectory>\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.16\components\simulator.

2. Append two entries

    SimulatorCommand9000-JDE = <Sim_install_dir>\fledge.exe /app=Jvm.dll /handheld=9000 /session=9000 /app-param=DisableRegistration /app-param=JvmAlxConfigFile:9000.xml /data-port=0x4d44 /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000A

    SimulatorDirectory9000-JDE= <Sim_install_dir>
```

note that  should be replaced with the actual path to where you installed the 9000 Bold simulator.